# Problemas al generar conjunto de datos haciendo uso de Random

Tags: python, random, dataset

Estoy tratando de crear un conjunto de datos para un sistema de generación que me gustaría hacer. El conjunto de datos en sí se compone de 5 datasets. El sistema que quiero crear debería ser capaz de, basándose en el historial de ventas de productos (alimentos), poder utilizar los ingredientes que componen las recetas de estos alimentos y generar diferentes secuencias de combinaciones diferentes de ingredientes, para formar alimentos nuevos.

Para esto, estoy utilizando las hamburguesas que tiene a la venta actualmente la cadena 'Burger King', y construyendo un conjunto de datos haciendo uso de la librería random de Python.

He mencionado que construyo 5 datasets diferentes, pero únicamente uno es el que me genera el problema (dataset que registra el historial de ventas de un año en concreto).
Los otros 4 datasets, recogen los distintos tipos de hamburguesas que hay a la venta (pollo, ternera, vegetal...), haciendo uso de una codificación ONE-HOT en cada fila (cada hamburguesa) para indicar que ingredientes lleva la hamburguesa, y cuales no.

Lo que ocurre es lo siguiente:
- Trato de generar el dataset, y se genera correctamente (400000 ejemplos; dos columnas ('nombreHamburguesa', 'Fecha_venta')).
- Al analizar el dataset, veo que se obtienen diferentes proporciones de hamburguesas según los tipos:
- 200000 de ternera.
- 80000 de pollo.
- ...

El problema principal es que, si tengo 200000 hamburguesas de ternera vendidas en un año, tras la creación del conjunto de datos el **número de apariciones de cada hamburguesa de ternera es practicamente identico**. Si tengo 10 hamburguesas de ternera diferentes a la venta, en el dataset generado, aparece que se ha vendido unas 20000 unidades de cada una.

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma diferentes de aplicar la misma lógica para la creación del dataset, y **obtener unas proporciones finales diferentes**.

---

**Código de generación de los conjuntos de datos**

```
    import pandas as pd
    import random
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import numpy as np


    def generarDataFramesHamburguesas():
    
        burgersTernera = ['Burger',
                          'Cheeseburger',
                          'Doble Cheeseburger',
                          'Rodeo Burger',
                          'Big King',
                          'Big King XXL',
                          'Doble Cheesebacon',
                          'Doble Cheesebacon XXL',
                          'Doble Cheeseburger BBQ',
                          'Whopper',
                          'Doble Whooper',
                          'Triple Whooper',
                          'Whopper Jr',
                          'The King Huevo (1 carne)',
                          'The King Huevo (2 carnes)',
                          'Steakhouse',
                          'Doble Steakhouse',
                          'Duo Bacon Cheddar Brioche (1 carne)',
                          'Duo Bacon Cheddar Brioche (2 carnes)',
                          'Cheesy Doritos (1 carne)',
                          'Cheesy Doritos (2 carnes)']
    
        burgersPollo = ['Chicken burguer',
                        'Crispy Chicken',
                        'Doble Crispy Chicken',
                        'Rodeo Burger pollo',
                        'Long Chicken',
                        'Chicken Wrap',
                        'King Chicken',
                        'Duo Bacon Cheddar Doble Crispy Chicken Brioche',
                        'Cheesy Doritos Crispy Chicken']
    
        burgersSinGluten = ['Whopper sin gluten',
                            'Burger sin gluten',
                            'CheeseBurger sin gluten']
    
    burgersVegetales = ['Cheesy Doritos Vegetal (1 carne)',
                        'Cheesy Doritos Vegetal (2 carnes)',
                        'Big King Vegetal',
                        'Long Vegetal',
                        'Whopper Vegetal',
                        'Doble Cheeseburger Vegetal',]
    
    ingHamburguesasTernera = {
        'Burger': 'Pan H1, Patty Ternera, Ketchup, Mostaza, Pepinillo',
        'Cheeseburger': 'Pan H1, Patty Ternera, Queso Cheddar, Ketchup, Mostaza, Pepinillo',
        'Doble Cheeseburger': 'Pan H1, Patty Ternera, Queso Cheddar, Ketchup, Mostaza, Pepinillo',
        'Rodeo Burger': 'Pan H3, Patty Ternera, Aros Cebolla, Salsa Barbacoa',
        'Big King': 'Pan H8, Patty Ternera, Queso Cheddar, Cebolla, Lechuga, Pepinillo, Salsa Big King',
        'Big King XXL': 'Pan H2, Carne Whopper, Queso Cheddar, Cebolla, Lechuga, Pepinillo, Salsa Big King',
        'Doble Cheesebacon': 'Pan H1, Patty Ternera, Queso Cheddar, Ketchup, Mostaza, Pepinillo, Bacon',
        'Doble Cheesebacon XXL': 'Pan H2, Carne Whopper, Queso Cheddar, Ketchup, Mostaza, Pepinillo, Bacon',
        'Doble Cheeseburger BBQ': 'Pan H1, Patty Ternera, Queso Cheddar, Salsa Barbacoa, Pepinillo',
        'Whopper': 'Pan H2, Carne Whopper, Lechuga, Cebolla, Tomate, Pepinillo, Ketchup, Mayonesa',
        'Doble Whooper': 'Pan H2, Carne Whopper, Lechuga, Cebolla, Tomate, Pepinillo, Ketchup, Mayonesa',
        'Triple Whooper': 'Pan H2, Carne Whopper, Lechuga, Cebolla, Tomate, Pepinillo, Ketchup, Mayonesa',
        'Whopper Jr': 'Pan H1, Patty Ternera, Lechuga, Cebolla, Tomate, Pepinillo, Ketchup, Mayonesa',
        'The King Huevo (1 carne)': 'Pan H2, Carne Whopper, Tomate, Cebolla frita, Huevo frito, Bacon, Queso Cheddar',
        'The King Huevo (2 carnes)': 'Pan H2, Carne Whopper, Tomate, Cebolla frita, Huevo frito, Bacon, Queso Cheddar',
        'Steakhouse': 'Pan H4, Carne Whopper, Lechuga, Tomate, Pepinillo, Salsa Barbacoa, Mayonesa',
        'Doble Steakhouse': 'Pan H4, Carne Whopper, Lechuga, Tomate, Pepinillo, Salsa Barbacoa, Mayonesa',
        'Duo Bacon Cheddar Brioche (1 carne)': 'Pan Brioche, Carne Whopper, Salsa Cheddar, Queso Cheddar, Bacon, Tomate, Cebolla frita',
        'Duo Bacon Cheddar Brioche (2 carnes)': 'Pan Brioche, Carne Whopper, Salsa Cheddar, Queso Cheddar, Bacon, Tomate, Cebolla frita',
        'Cheesy Doritos (1 carne)': 'Pan Doritos, Carne Whopper, Snack Doritos, Queso Cheddar, Salsa cheddar Doritos',
        'Cheesy Doritos (2 carnes)': 'Pan Doritos, Carne Whopper, Snack Doritos, Queso Cheddar, Salsa cheddar Doritos'
    }
    
    ingHamburguesasPollo = {
        'Chicken burguer': 'Pan H1, Patty Pollo, Mayonesa, Lechuga',
        'Crispy Chicken': 'Pan H1, Carne Crispy, Mayonesa, Lechuga, Tomate',
        'Doble Crispy Chicken': 'Pan H1, Carne Crispy, Mayonesa, Lechuga, Tomate',
        'Rodeo Burger pollo': 'Pan H3, Patty Pollo, Aros Cebolla, Salsa Barbacoa',
        'Long Chicken': 'Pan H3, Carne Long, Mayonesa, Lechuga',
        'Chicken Wrap': 'Rollito, Carne Crispy, Mayonesa, Lechuga, Tomate, Queso Cheddar',
        'King Chicken': 'Pan rustico, Bacon, Pollo premium, Salsa Relish, Tomate, Canonigos y rucula, Queso Cheddar',
        'Duo Bacon Cheddar Doble Crispy Chicken Brioche': 'Pan Brioche, Carne Crispy, Bacon, Queso Cheddar, Tomate, Cebolla frita, Salsa Cheddar',
        'Cheesy Doritos Crispy Chicken': 'Pan Doritos, Carne Crispy, Snack Doritos, Queso Cheddar, Salsa cheddar Doritos, Tomate'
    }
    
    ingHamburguesasSinGluten = {
        'Whopper sin gluten': 'Pan sin gluten, Carne Whopper, Lechuga, Cebolla, Tomate, Pepinillo, Ketchup, Mayonesa sin gluten',
        'Burger sin gluten': 'Pan sin gluten, Carne Whopper, Pepinillo, Ketchup',
        'CheeseBurger sin gluten':'Pan sin gluten, Carne Whopper, Pepinillo, Ketchup, Queso Cheddar'
    }
    
    ingHamburguesasVegetales = {
        'Cheesy Doritos Vegetal (1 carne)': 'Pan Doritos, Carne Rebel Whopper, Snack Doritos, Queso Cheddar, Salsa cheddar Doritos, Tomate',
        'Cheesy Doritos Vegetal (2 carnes)': 'Pan Doritos, Carne Rebel Whopper, Snack Doritos, Queso Cheddar, Salsa cheddar Doritos, Tomate',
        'Big King Vegetal': 'Pan H8, Patty Vegetal, Queso Cheddar, Cebolla, Lechuga, Pepinillo, Salsa Big King',
        'Long Vegetal': 'Pan H3, Carne Long Vegetal, Lechuga, Mayonesa',
        'Whopper Vegetal': 'Pan H2, Carne Rebel Whopper, Lechuga, Cebolla, Tomate, Pepinillo, Ketchup, Mayonesa',
        'Doble Cheeseburger Vegetal': 'Pan H1, Patty Vegetal, Queso Cheddar, Ketchup, Mostaza, Pepinillo',
    }
    
    listaIngredientesTernera = []
    for valor in ingHamburguesasTernera.values(): # <-- Recorro el dict de ternera y añado cada valor de las parejas a la lista.
        listaIngredientesTernera.append(valor)
        
        
    listaIngredientesPollo = []
    for valor in ingHamburguesasPollo.values(): # <-- Recorro el dict de pollo y añado cada valor de las parejas a la lista.
        listaIngredientesPollo.append(valor)
        
    listaIngredientesSinGluten = []
    for valor in ingHamburguesasSinGluten.values():
        listaIngredientesSinGluten.append(valor)
    
    listaIngredientesVegetales = []
    for valor in ingHamburguesasVegetales.values():
        listaIngredientesVegetales.append(valor)
    
        
        
        
    recetasTernera = []    # <-- Creo una nueva lista y añado los ingredientes por separado
    for ingredientes in listaIngredientesTernera:
        recetasTernera.append(ingredientes.split(','))
        
    recetasPollo = []    # <-- Creo una nueva lista y añado los ingredientes por separado
    for ingredientes in listaIngredientesPollo:
        recetasPollo.append(ingredientes.split(','))
        
    recetasSinGluten = []    # <-- Creo una nueva lista y añado los ingredientes por separado
    for ingredientes in listaIngredientesSinGluten:
        recetasSinGluten.append(ingredientes.split(','))
        
    recetasVegetales = []
    for ingredientes in listaIngredientesVegetales:
        recetasVegetales.append(ingredientes.split(','))
        

    # Crear una lista plana de todos los ingredientes
    ingredientesTernera = [ingrediente for receta in recetasTernera for ingrediente in receta]

    # Crear una lista plana de todos los ingredientes
    ingredientesPollo = [ingrediente for receta in recetasPollo for ingrediente in receta]
    
    # Crear una lista plana de todos los ingredientes
    ingredientesSinGluten = [ingrediente for receta in recetasSinGluten for ingrediente in receta]
    
    ingredientesVegetales = [ingrediente for receta in recetasVegetales for ingrediente in receta]
    
    
    
    # Obtener ingredientes únicos
    ingredientesTernera_unicos = list(set(ingredientesTernera))
    
    ingredientesPollo_unicos = list(set(ingredientesPollo))
    
    ingredientesSinGluten_unicos = list(set(ingredientesSinGluten))
    
    ingredientesVegetales_unicos = list(set(ingredientesVegetales))



    df_ternera = pd.DataFrame(index=burgersTernera, columns=ingredientesTernera_unicos)
    df_pollo = pd.DataFrame(index=burgersPollo, columns=ingredientesPollo_unicos)
    df_sinGluten = pd.DataFrame(index=burgersSinGluten, columns=ingredientesSinGluten_unicos)
    df_vegetales = pd.DataFrame(index=burgersVegetales, columns=ingredientesVegetales_unicos)


    for i, receta in enumerate(recetasTernera):
        fila = {ingrediente: 1 if ingrediente in receta else 0 for ingrediente in ingredientesTernera_unicos}
        df_ternera.loc[burgersTernera[i]] = fila

    for i, receta in enumerate(recetasPollo):
        fila = {ingrediente: 1 if ingrediente in receta else 0 for ingrediente in ingredientesPollo_unicos}
        df_pollo.loc[burgersPollo[i]] = fila
        
    for i, receta in enumerate(recetasSinGluten):
        fila = {ingrediente: 1 if ingrediente in receta else 0 for ingrediente in ingredientesSinGluten_unicos}
        df_sinGluten.loc[burgersSinGluten[i]] = fila

    for i, receta in enumerate(recetasVegetales):
        fila = {ingrediente: 1 if ingrediente in receta else 0 for ingrediente in ingredientesVegetales_unicos}
        df_vegetales.loc[burgersVegetales[i]] = fila
        
    return df_ternera, df_pollo, df_sinGluten, df_vegetales




def generarDatasetHamburguesas(df_ternera, df_pollo, df_sinGluten, df_vegetales):
    
    df_ternera.to_csv('hamburguesas_ternera.csv')
    df_pollo.to_csv('hamburguesas_pollo.csv')
    df_sinGluten.to_csv('hamburguesas_sinGluten.csv')
    df_vegetales.to_csv('hamburguesas_vegetales.csv')
    
    return 'Dataset de hamburguesas creados!'














if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    df_ternera, df_pollo, df_sinGluten, df_vegetales = generarDataFramesHamburguesas()
    

    burgers = df_ternera.index # <-- Obtengo los nombres de todas las hamburguesas de ternera.
    pollo = df_pollo.index # <-- Obtengo los nombres de todas las hamburguesas de pollo.
    sinGluten = df_sinGluten.index
    vegetales = df_vegetales.index
    
    #generarDatasetHamburguesas(df_ternera, df_pollo, df_sinGluten, df_vegetales)
    
    
  
     # Defino el periodo de tiempo en el que se registrarán las ventas del dataset.
    fecha_inicial = datetime(2022, 1, 1)
    fecha_final = datetime(2022, 12, 31)
    
    verano_inicio = datetime(2022, 6, 21)
    verano_final = datetime(2022, 9, 21)
    
    navidad_inicio = datetime(2022, 12, 25)
    navidad_final = datetime(2022, 12, 31)
    
    fechas_aleatorias = []

    historialHamburguesasVendidas = []
    contador = 0
    while contador < 400000:
        
        dia = random.randint(1,10)
        diasVerano = [4,5,6]
        diasNavidad = [1]
        
        numero = random.randint(1,25)
        if numero <= 14:
            hamburguesa = random.choice(burgers)
            historialHamburguesasVendidas.append(hamburguesa)
            
            if dia in diasVerano:
                delta = verano_final - verano_inicio
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                fecha_aleatoria = verano_inicio + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
            elif dia in diasNavidad:
                delta = navidad_final - navidad_inicio
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                fecha_aleatoria = navidad_inicio + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
            else:
                 
                # Calcular un delta de tiempo aleatorio dentro del rango de fechas
                delta = fecha_final - fecha_inicial
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                # Crear una fecha aleatoria sumando el delta a la fecha inicial
                fecha_aleatoria = fecha_inicial + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                # Agregar la fecha aleatoria a la lista
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
        elif numero >= 15 and numero <= 19:
            hamburguesa = random.choice(pollo)
            historialHamburguesasVendidas.append(hamburguesa)
        
            if dia in diasVerano:
                delta = verano_final - verano_inicio
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                fecha_aleatoria = verano_inicio + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
            elif dia in diasNavidad:
                delta = navidad_final - navidad_inicio
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                fecha_aleatoria = navidad_inicio + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
            else:
                 
                # Calcular un delta de tiempo aleatorio dentro del rango de fechas
                delta = fecha_final - fecha_inicial
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                # Crear una fecha aleatoria sumando el delta a la fecha inicial
                fecha_aleatoria = fecha_inicial + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                # Agregar la fecha aleatoria a la lista
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
        elif numero >= 20 and numero <= 21:
            hamburguesa = random.choice(sinGluten)
            historialHamburguesasVendidas.append(hamburguesa)
        
            if dia in diasVerano:
                delta = verano_final - verano_inicio
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                fecha_aleatoria = verano_inicio + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
            elif dia in diasNavidad:
                delta = navidad_final - navidad_inicio
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                fecha_aleatoria = navidad_inicio + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
            else:
                 
                # Calcular un delta de tiempo aleatorio dentro del rango de fechas
                delta = fecha_final - fecha_inicial
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                # Crear una fecha aleatoria sumando el delta a la fecha inicial
                fecha_aleatoria = fecha_inicial + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                # Agregar la fecha aleatoria a la lista
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
        elif numero >= 22 and numero <= 24:
            hamburguesa = random.choice(vegetales)
            historialHamburguesasVendidas.append(hamburguesa)
            
            if dia in diasVerano:
                delta = verano_final - verano_inicio
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                fecha_aleatoria = verano_inicio + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
            elif dia in diasNavidad:
                delta = navidad_final - navidad_inicio
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                fecha_aleatoria = navidad_inicio + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
            
            else:
                 
                # Calcular un delta de tiempo aleatorio dentro del rango de fechas
                delta = fecha_final - fecha_inicial
                random_delta = random.randint(0, delta.days)
                
                # Crear una fecha aleatoria sumando el delta a la fecha inicial
                fecha_aleatoria = fecha_inicial + timedelta(days=random_delta)
                
                # Agregar la fecha aleatoria a la lista
                fechas_aleatorias.append(fecha_aleatoria)
                
                contador +=1
    else:
        'Historial de ventas creado!'
        
    datasetFinal = pd.DataFrame({'Hamburguesa': historialHamburguesasVendidas, 'Fecha_venta': fechas_aleatorias})
    
    datasetFinal.to_csv('conjuntoVentasVerano2022.csv')
    print('Dataset creado!')
```

---

**Imágenes relacionadas**

Ventas hamburguesas de pollo:

[image: Visualización de ventas para todas las hamburguesas de ternera]

Ventas totales de cada tipo de hamburguesa en el conjunto de datos:

[image: Ventas de cada tipo de hamburguesas]

Comment: La función `random` te garantiza una distribución uniforme por construcción. Puedes obtener otras distribuciones con diferentes operaciones: rand()+rand() distribución gaussiana, mod(rand()) distribución en sierra, etc. En el módulo random tienes algunas de estas [distribuciones](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#real-valued-distributions) listas para usar.

Comment: Entiendo, algo que llegué a imaginar. Le echaré un vistazo al resto de distribuciones en random. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar una lista de selecciones aleatorias usando distintos pesos, que podrías determinar también de manera aleatoria, valiéndote de la función [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices).

Esta función te devuelve una lista de k elementos, en base a una lista con *pesos* que representan la probabilidad de que cada elemento sea seleccionado para formar la lista final.

Estos pesos no son porcentajes, el % de probabilidad para cada elemento de la lista se calcula en base al peso dado para el elemento y la suma de los pesos de todos los elementos.

He preparado un pequeño ejemplo con una lista de 4 hamburguesas y dándole a cada una un peso aleatorio entre 10 y 40, he generado una lista de 1000 *ventas* con una llamada a `choices()` y luego he contado cuántas hamburguesas de cada una se han incluido en la lista y el porcentaje que estas representan de las 1000 ventas.

Para que la salida sea más fácil de procesar, también he calculado el % que cada peso representa del peso total, en el entendido que esto no es necesario, pero ayuda a verificar el comportamiento.

Luego he impreso en pantalla la lista de pesos con su porcentaje, y el resultado del conteo de cada hamburguesa, con el número de unidades vendidas y el % que representa del total de ventas.

El script resultante es:

```
import random

burgersEjemplo = ['Burger', 'Cheesburger', 'Doble Cheesburger', 'Rodeo Burger']

pesoTotal = 0
pesos = list()
contadoresVentas = list()
pesosPorcentaje = list()
for i in range(len(burgersEjemplo)):
    peso = random.randrange(10, 40)
    pesoTotal += peso
    pesos.append(peso)

burgersVentas = random.choices(burgersEjemplo, weights=pesos, k=1000)

for burger in burgersEjemplo:
    contadoresVentas.append((burger, burgersVentas.count(burger), "{:.2f}%".format(burgersVentas.count(burger) / 10)))
for peso in pesos:
    pesosPorcentaje.append((peso, "{:.2f}%".format(100 * peso / pesoTotal)))

print(pesosPorcentaje)
print(contadoresVentas)
```

3 corridas de prueba producen la siguiente salida:

```
[(28, '28.28%'), (29, '29.29%'), (30, '30.30%'), (12, '12.12%')]
[('Burger', 293, '29.30%'), ('Cheesburger', 279, '27.90%'), ('Doble Cheesburger', 304, '30.40%'), ('Rodeo Burger', 124, '12.40%')]

[(15, '18.99%'), (22, '27.85%'), (29, '36.71%'), (13, '16.46%')]
[('Burger', 192, '19.20%'), ('Cheesburger', 269, '26.90%'), ('Doble Cheesburger', 384, '38.40%'), ('Rodeo Burger', 155, '15.50%')]

[(25, '29.41%'), (16, '18.82%'), (31, '36.47%'), (13, '15.29%')]
[('Burger', 291, '29.10%'), ('Cheesburger', 194, '19.40%'), ('Doble Cheesburger', 370, '37.00%'), ('Rodeo Burger', 145, '14.50%')]
```

Como puedes observar, si bien los números no son exactos, la distribución cumple con aproximarse a los pesos solicitados.

Creo que con esto tienes lo necesario para superar el problema que planteas en la pregunta.

Comment: Lo tengo solucionado, siguiendo de forma muy similar la lógica que planteas en la respuesta. Muchas gracias por tu colaboración.